# What do objects mean in CERN's collision visualisation?

Tags: nuclear-physics, collision, large-hadron-collider, visualization

Trying to find a legend for some of the collision visualisations from CERN's [CMS](https://home.cern/resources/image/experiments/cms-images-gallery), [ALICE](https://home.cern/resources/image/experiments/alice-images-gallery) or [other experiments](https://home.cern/resources/image/experiments). The visualisation below is from the [CMS Higgs Seminar (4 July 2012)](https://cds.cern.ch/search?f=keyword&p=higgsjuly4&ln=en). What are the things in the picture? Thanks.

[image: proton-proton collision CMS, CERN]

> Event recorded with the CMS detector in 2012 at a proton-proton centre of mass energy of 8 TeV. The event shows characteristics expected from the decay of the SM Higgs boson to a pair of photons (dashed yellow lines and green towers). The event could also be due to known standard model background processes.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The picture you link is not an *illustration*. It is a display of the measurement of one proton on proton interaction, from real numbers gathered at a specific time in the experiment, modeled with mathematical functions . [This answer of mine](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/679928/how-are-paths-of-particles-tracked-in-particle-accelerators/679985#679985) might help.

[This is an *illustration*](https://cds.cern.ch/record/2120661) of how the detectors measure the various components.

[image: cmsslice]

The two dashed lines are the two photons that make up the particular higgs decay, their energy and direction measured in the electromagnetic calorimeter.

The full lines are charged particles measured in the tracking detector.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, could you please expand on it a little bit. I would like to understand why yellow dotted lines transition into green 3d shapes? What are the 3d shapes to the sides: green and dark orange on the left hand-side; blue, green and distant white shapes on the right hand-side?

Comment: The yellow are the neutral photons , gamma rays, they do motleave a track in the tracking chamber , and the green is the display of the position and size of the energy they disposit in the electromagnetic calorimeter. They have not drawn lines for all the other energy deposits because the picture would be too croweded to display the Higgs decay, the paralelograms are displaying the size left by neutral particles seen in the hadronic and electromagnetic calorimeter.